# increase how frequently arduino uno records data

Tags: arduino, record

I am currently using an Arduino Uno to record data from a light-emitting circuit to my computer to measure how fast seeds are falling to in turn measure the terminal velocity of these seeds.

Currently it records a voltage reading from the circuits about every 15 milliseconds.

However, I need it to record the voltage more often to capture the seeds that are small and fall quickly.

- Is this possible with an Arduino Uno?
- Do I need to use something else?

The code I am using is pasted below.  It's quite simple code, but I did not write it so I am unfamiliar with how to edit it to see if it can record more frequently.

```
    //int sensorValue_1;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
    //int sensorValue_2;
    //int sensorValue_3;
    //unsigned long time1;
    //unsigned long time2;
    //unsigned long time3;

     void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial
    }

    void loop() {
      // read the value from the sensor:
      //analogRead(A0);
      //delay(2);
      Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
      Serial.write(' ,');
      Serial.print(millis());
      Serial.write(' ,');

      //analogRead(A1);
      //delay(2);
      Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
      Serial.write(' ,');
      Serial.print(millis());

      Serial.write('\n');
    }
```

Comment: why two analog pins are read?

Comment: Instead of communicating the value as soon as you read it, store it in a buffer and send it every second or so. This will increase the reading frequency.

Comment: `' ,'` is not a valid character.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the speed of your code by changing the baud rate to 115200. This makes the communication between your PC and the Arduino a lot faster so the program can write more data within the same timeframe.

This would be the new code then:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);          //  setup serial
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
  Serial.write(',');
  Serial.print(millis());
  Serial.write(',');

  Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
  Serial.write(',');
  Serial.print(millis());

  Serial.write('\n');
}
```

When using Arduino's Serial Monitor for viewing the data, you can change the baud rate in the right corner from 9600 baud to 115200 baud to see the correct data.

You can even change the baud rate to an even higher rate like 1000000 but I've not tested this before.

Answer (score 0):

Why use analogueRead()? Surely to measure the velocity you are timing the seed passing two points a known distance apart? This could be a digital pulse.

I would use interrupts on two different pins, start and stop. The interrupt handler would just record the timestamp when triggered. The main loop would check for both values, do the maths and report the result.